# Build "*.DTPROJ" - SSIS on the build server with devenv.exe (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, ssis

I'm trying to build a SSIS project (*.dtproj) with Visual Studio 2012 on the build server.

As far as I know there's no support to build this kind of project directly using MSBuild.

However my thinking is that if I can build it using the Visual Studio 2012 IDE locally, I would be able to build it using the Visual Studio command line (calling devenv.exe/devenv.com) directly from a command line on the build server

But I have tried so many combinations and I have not been able to find anything that works

I keep receiving the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.60315.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Error: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the command line I'm using:

```
."C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" .\Datawarehouse_ETL.sln /ReBuild Development /Project .\Datawarehouse_ETL\Datawarehouse_ETL.dtproj /ProjectConfig Development /Log .\output.log /out .\output.log
```

I think I have a problem with the parameters I'm using to call `devenv.com`

But according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx)

> **/Build (devenv.exe)** This switch performs the same function as the Build Solution menu command within the integrated development environment (IDE).
>   Enclose strings that include spaces in double quotation marks.
>   Summary information for builds, including errors, can be displayed in the Command window, or in any log file specified with the /out switch.
>   This command only builds projects that have changed since the last build. To build all projects in a solution, use /Rebuild (devenv.exe).

I have found several forums with this question but none of the workarounds proposed there have worked for me.

BTW [according to this post](http://codeissue.com/issues/i34f27f07da473e/difference-between-devenv-com-vs-devenv-exe), `devenv.com` is just a wrapper on top of `devenv.exe` to be used as a command line

I'm about to give up and just build the solution manually/locally and check in the `*.ispac` file generated after building and just write a PowerShell script to deploy that =(((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was bug in initial release of SSDT-BI which was fixed in the following release
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Find here response from Microsoft Feedback site for above probelm
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781872/fail-to-build-ssis-ssas-projects-via-vs2012-command-line-devenv-exe-with-ssdt-bi-tool-installed